# how to combine multiple rows into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

My table:

```
id  val
--------
 a   1   
 a   2
 a   3
 b   7
 b   8
 b   9
 b   10
```

What i want to get is:

```
id  val1  val2  val3  val4
--------------------------
a    1     2     3    null
b    7     8     9     10
```

Is there any simple way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` combined with pivoting logic provides one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN val END) AS val1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN val END) AS val2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN val END) AS val3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN val END) AS val4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same output, but worth considering:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(val)
    FROM tbl GROUP BY id;
```